# Can't parse String to LocalDate (Java 8)

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

My input is a String representation of a date in the format "01-07-2015" for July 1, 2015. I'm trying to parse this into a `java.time.LocalDate` variable:

```
final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-YYYY");
final String input = "01-07-2015";
final LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(input, DATE_FORMAT);
```

Based on the [`DateTimeFormatter` JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), I would expect this to work. However, I'm greeted with a very friendly and helpful message:

> Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=1, MonthOfYear=7, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[MONDAY,4]]=2015},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed

I don't really understand what this exception is telling me. Can anyone explain me what's going wrong?

Comment: You should choose `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For year you have to use the lowercase y:

```
final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Uppercase Y is used for weekyear. See the [javadoc of DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for more details.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does the error message relate to the fact that `Y` is for _weekyear_ while `y` is for _year_?

Comment: Error message says {DayOfMonth=1, MonthOfYear=7, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[MONDAY,4]]=2015}, it means it parsed 1 from your input string as DayOfMonth (because you used "d" in your pattern), 7 was was parsed as MonthOfYear (because of "M" in your pattern) and 2015 was understood as WeekBasedYear (aka weekyear) becaues of "Y" in your pattern

Comment: @mthmulders Sometimes [exception messages suck](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/278949/why-do-many-exception-messages-not-contain-useful-details). Granted, that exception isn't really all that bad, and it does tell you what it tried to parse `YYYY` as. I looked up [java datetimeformatter weekbasedyear](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+datetimeformatter+weekbasedyear) and the first result led me [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), which lists the identifier types and what they mean.

Answer (score 23):

The answer to the question is to use 'y' not 'Y'.

To explain the error message, lets decompose it:

`Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor`

This is saying that it cannot create a `LocalDate` (what was requested) from a `TemporalAccessor` (the low-level interface that provides hashmap-like access to the fields of date/time).

`of type java.time.format.Parsed`

This is saying that the object passed into the method was of type `java.time.format.Parsed`. This is the standard output type of parsing, and contains all the information that was parsed.

`{DayOfMonth=1, MonthOfYear=7, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[MONDAY,4]]=2015},ISO`

This is the `toString()` form of the `java.time.format.Parsed` object that resulted from parsing. It is saying that four things were parsed:

- `DayOfMonth=1`, the day-of-month parsed with value of `1`
- `MonthOfYear=7`, the month-of-year parsed with value of `7`
- `WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[MONDAY,4]]=2015`, the week-based-year parsed with value of `2015`
- `ISO`, which is the ISO calendar system (a default value)

Since it is not possible to produce a `LocalDate` from the combination DayOfMonth + MonthOfYear + WeekBasedYear, an exception is thrown.

Note that the `[WeekFields[MONDAY,4]]` part refers to the fact that there are many different ways to define a week, in the US weeks start on Sunday, but in the ISO standard and the EU they start on Monday.