# What pattern of datetimeformat is needed for DateTimeFormatter to parse JAN01/2020?

Tags: java, datetime-format

I'm being passed a date in ths format - "JAN01/2020" but I can't seem to find the DateTimeFormatter pattern for it. I tried these (as well as several others) but they're resulting in DateTimeParseException -

```
 DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMd/YYYY").parse("JAN01/2020")
 DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMdd/YYYY").parse("JAN01/2020")
```

I also considered this post's solution and the three lines below also result in DateTimeParseException. It does not appear to be a case-sensitivity issue
[Java 8 DateTimeFormatter for month in all CAPS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520491/java-8-datetimeformatter-for-month-in-all-caps-not-working)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter= DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMdd/yyyy");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("JAN14/2020", formatter);
System.out.println(dateTime.getYear());
```

I appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 4):

## Case-sensitive

The main problem with your format is, you are using `YYYY` instead of `yyyy`. Do it as follows:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                            .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                            .appendPattern("MMMd/yyyy")
                                            .toFormatter();
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("JAN01/2020", formatter));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-01-01
```

**Demo of using `DateTimeFormatter::parse` with it:**

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendPattern("MMMd/yyyy")
                .toFormatter();
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("JAN01/2020"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{},ISO resolved to 2020-01-01
```

Comment: Trying to understand this, why doesn't this work with 'y' lowercase or uppercase- DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMd/yyyy").parse and DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMd/YYYY").parse are throwing the same exception

Answer (score 4):

You may

- handle the case with use of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`

  - `.parseCaseInsensitive()` for the case of the month, `MMM` is for `Jan` and you have `JAN`
  - `.appendPattern("MMMdd/yyyy")` for the pattern
- parse into a `LocalDate` as there is no time composant

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive().appendPattern("MMMdd/yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = builder.toFormatter();

LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse("JAN14/2020", dateFormat);
System.out.println(dateTime); // 2020-01-14
```

## [`CODE DEMO`](https://repl.it/repls/PersonalEvenBrowser)

Comment: Trying to understand this, why doesn't this work with 'y' lowercase-
 DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMd/yyyy").parse("JAN01/2020")

Comment: Uppercase or lowercase, both will not work? If it's because of case then wouldn't one be correct?

Comment: What's the distinction here, this works fine with month total UPPERCASE - DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yyyy").parse("01-Aug-2019")

Comment: @Moshe `Aug` is not total uppercase, total uppercase is `AUG` ;) it's about the value, not the pattern. Read my post again, i've explain where is the problem about the case

Comment: @Moshe you may now think about accepting an answer, is one solves your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. As the question you are linking to says, you need to use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` for case insensitive parsing of your month abbreviation in upper case.
2. Beware of the case of format pattern letters. `yyyy` and `YYYY` are different. See for example [this question: Can't parse String to LocalDate (Java 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605411/cant-parse-string-to-localdate-java-8).
3. Supply a locale for your formatter. If `JAN` is English, then supply an English-speaking locale. For example:

   ```
       new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
               .parseCaseInsensitive()
               .appendPattern("MMMdd/yyyy")
               .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)
   ```
4. As azro said, since you haven’t got a time of day, parse into a `LocalDate`, not a `LocalDateTime` (or specify a default hour of day on the builder to be able to parse into a `LocalDateTime`, but I don’t see the advantage).